# how do I find the contents of a line by matching the column number?

Tags: sed, awk

I have a flat file with names, addresses, and other data.  Most of the lines have an 11-digit number starting at column 299, but some are blank.

I can't match on a particular string because I am looking for those lines where column 299 to column 309 (11 characters) is empty, i.e., blank.

How can I do this in Unix?  Is this something to do using sed or should I use AWK?

Comment: can you provide example file and desired output?

Comment: `123 John Doe 9999 Park Ave NY NY 10016                      123456789`
`124 Jane Doe 14685 Sleepover Blvd Apt 7 Atlanta GA 90999    `
`125 Joe Blow 15 Main St San Diego CA 98765                  456789123`


I need to pull out the lines like Jane has, where the number is a certain specific number of characters to the right but she has no number there.  Thanks.

Comment: oh man I despise this editing environment, sorry.  The nine-digit numbers should have line feeds so the three example lines are one above the other.

Comment: Hm. I don't fully understand your algorithm. If you wish to operate with characters, I will suggest use `cut -c`, for operating with fields, use `cut -f` (or `awk`). If you describe your algorithm more, I will provide working solution.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. `cat myfile | cut -c 99-109` gives me the contents of each line of the file.  All I need to know now is how to output the line number whenever there is no content.

Comment: Hm, in example there no lines longer than 55 characters. BTW, your command demonstrates `useless cat usage` (http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)

Comment: There many ways to achieve that. Please, show example of input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk '{if (substr($0,299,11)=="")print $0}' file
```

Comment: That does it! Thank you, I obviously didn't understand awk syntax, I was trying something like that without the "if" - duh.

Many thanks to both of you.  Cheers!

Comment: I don't think that'll work, as there will be 11 blank character instead of `""`...

Comment: Thanks, beny, in my case it works because blanks in the file are filled with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
awk 'substr($0, 99, 11) == sprintf("%*s", 11, " ")' input.txt
```

Will print all lines with blanks for 11 characters from position 99.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
<input_file sed -e '/^.\{98\} \{11\}/!d;=' | sed -e '1~2!d'
```

This prints the line numbers of lines from `input_file` with 11 spaces from column 99
If its from column 299 change `\{98\}` to `\{298\}`